In my case XGBoost is faster than LightGBM. How do I achieve better speed?
I hope that this place is the right one to ask the following question:
I'm training a machine learning model.
The train size is 85000x55. 49x float32 and 6x int32.
It's a regression task. I tried many different models but now I'm sticking to LightGBM[4.4.0] and XGBoost[2.1.0] (both build with pip install xgboost lightgbm on a Windows machine with 36 cores).
Both algorithms performs really good, but LightGBM is about 4% better.
I've read that LightGBM is faster than XGBoost. But in my case XGBoost is about 70% faster. Why is that?
I would love to keep using LightGBM and having the speed of XGBoost. Am I doing something wrong or is there something I can tweak?
This is how I create the model in both cases
model = XGBRegressor(n_jobs=-1)
model = LGBMRegressor(n_jobs=-1, verbose=-1, force_col_wise=True)


why is XGB a regressor, but LGBM a classifier?

oh sorry... both are Regressors... Changed the code
